# How can I get my western digital hd to work?

Tags: 12.04, mount, hard-drive, nas

The program in the hd won't respond to the cursor.

Comment: Care to elaborate? What program?

Comment: The program in my WD Elements hd refuses to work with ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: But what kind of program is it? You trying to run an application from your external hard-drive? Or what? An .exe file?

Comment: I think what he is talking about is the elements smartware software it ships with. (backup software) Although he is vague.

Comment: Exactly. The elements smartware software does not work on ubuntu 12.04.  What do i do?

Answer (score 2):

Smartware does not support Linux and there is absolutely nothing you can use to get it working. This software is aimed strictly at Windows users (and we all know why ;) )

To me this is a possible security risk: it auto mounts by default so should someone get hold of your drive and load malware on that partition you could be setup for some serious problems. If you are only using Ubuntu you can use gParted to remove that software and free up some space that you can actually use.

You might want to look up Déjà Dup or Back In Time as two recent, popular backup programs with graphical interfaces. You will find them in the software repository.